# Where to find Solace SEMP XSD file

Tags: solace

We have a Solace appliance in house.  I would like to know where I get the SEMP xsd file (semp-rpc-soltr.xsd).  Is it available in developer portal?

Answer (score 0):

The SEMP Request Schema file (semp-rpc-soltr.xsd) is available on the Solace developer portal in the Products category of the Downloads page under 'Virtual Message Router' or 'Virtual Message Router - Cloud Images'.

You can access the the Downloads page of the Solace developer portal here:
http://dev.solacesystems.com/downloads/